# Pandas enumerate groups in descending order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I've the following column:

```
   column
0      10
1      10
2       8
3       8
4       6
5       6
```

My goal is to find the today unique values (3 in this case) and create a new column which would create the following

```
   new_column
0           3
1           3
2           2
3           2
4           1
5           1
```

The numbering starts from length of unique values (3) and same number is repeated if current row is same as previous row based on original column. Number gets decreased as row value changes. All unique values in original column have same number of rows (2 rows for each unique value in this case).

My solution was to groupby the original column and create a new list like below:

```
i=1
new_time=[]
for j, v in df.groupby('column'):
    new_time.append([i]*2)
    i=i+1
```

Then I'd flatten the list sort in decreasing order. Any other simpler solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `GroupBy.ngroup` with `ascending=False`:

```
df.groupby('column', sort=False).ngroup(ascending=False)+1

0    3
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    1
5    1
dtype: int64
```

---

For DataFrame that looks like this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': [10, 10, 8, 8, 10, 10]})
```

. . .where only consecutive values are to be grouped, you'll need to modify your grouper:

```
(df.groupby(df['column'].ne(df['column'].shift()).cumsum(), sort=False)
   .ngroup(ascending=False)
   .add(1))

0    3
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    1
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @anky_91 Actully, scratch that, it seems like it assigns factors based on the first encountered value.

Comment: That is a huge difference between `pd.factorize` and `np.unique`.  `pd.factorize` doesn't sort while `np.unique` does.  @anky_91

Comment: @piRSquared noted. :) had a gut feeling with factorize , just wasnt sure. :)

Comment: @cs95 we can also use `rank`. Do see my answer.

Comment: @BharathM I've upvoted (nice to see you!) However I'm not sure it will work in general. Rank will rank values by magnitude, not in order of appearance (as is the requirement here).

Comment: @cs95 I totally misunderstood I guess. Now I saw the second part of the answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

#### `pd.factorize`

```
i, u = pd.factorize(df.column)
df.assign(new=len(u) - i)

   column  new
0      10    3
1      10    3
2       8    2
3       8    2
4       6    1
5       6    1
```

---

#### `dict.setdefault`

```
d = {}
for k in df.column:
    d.setdefault(k, len(d))

df.assign(new=len(d) - df.column.map(d))
```

Answer (score 3):

Acutally, we can use `rank` with method being `dense` i.e

> **dense**: like ‘min’, but rank always increases by 1 between groups

```
df['column'].rank(method='dense')

0    3.0
1    3.0
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
```

`rank` version of @cs95's solution would be

```
df['column'].ne(df['column'].shift()).cumsum().rank(method='dense',ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with  `unique` and `map`

```
df.column.map(dict(zip(df.column.unique(),reversed(range(df.column.nunique())))))+1
Out[350]: 
0    3
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    1
5    1
Name: column, dtype: int64
```

Comment: See [piR's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720806/pandas-enumerate-groups-in-descending-order/56720838#comment100002670_56720838), this will sort the data before assigning groups and is likely not what OP wants (groups should be assigned in the order the data is present).

Comment: @cs95 I am trying to fixed that , brb

Comment: It seems hacky but definitely better than before. Thanks :)

Comment: Swap positions of the 10's and 8s and you'll see.

Comment: @piRSquared that is hard without sort with np.unique , and fixed \

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want groupID of same-values consecutive groups in reversed order. If so, I think this should work too:

```
df.column.nunique() - df.column.ne(df.column.shift()).cumsum().sub(1)

Out[691]:
0    3
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    1
5    1
Name: column, dtype: int32
```