# Reset 'Id' value of appended Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, append

I have appended multiple dataframes to form single dataframe. Each dataframe had multiple rows assigned with specific ID. After appending, Big dataframe has multiple rows with same Id. Would like assign new id's.

Current Dataframe:

```
Index   name     groupid
  0      Abc       0
  1      cvb       0
  2      sdf       0
  3      ksh       1
  4      kjl       1
  5      lmj       2
  6      hyb       2
  0      khf       0
  1      uyt       0
  2      tre       1
  3      awe       1
  4      uys       2
  5      asq       2
  6      lsx       2
```

Desired Output:

```
Index   name     groupid    new_id
  0      Abc       0          0 
  1      cvb       0          0
  2      sdf       0          0
  3      ksh       1          1
  4      kjl       1          1
  5      lmj       2          2
  6      hyb       2          2
  7      khf       0          3  
  8      uyt       0          3
  9      tre       1          4
  10     awe       1          4
  11     uys       2          5
  12     asq       2          5
  13     lsx       2          5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a slightly modified version of `groupby`:

```
df['new_id'] = df.groupby(df['groupid'].ne(df['groupid'].shift()).cumsum(), sort=False)
                          .ngroup())
```

Output is:

```
    Index name  groupid  new_id
0       0  Abc        0       0
1       1  cvb        0       0
2       2  sdf        0       0
3       3  ksh        1       1
4       4  kjl        1       1
5       5  lmj        2       2
6       6  hyb        2       2
7       0  khf        0       3
8       1  uyt        0       3
9       2  tre        1       4
10      3  awe        1       4
11      4  uys        2       5
12      5  asq        2       5
13      6  lsx        2       5
```

See [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720806/pandas-enumerate-groups-in-descending-order) for reference.